# HBase table size is much bigger than the file in hadoop hdfs

Tags: hadoop, hbase, hdfs

Recently I use hadoop bulk load to put data into hbase
Firstly, I call HDFS API to write data into file in hadoop hdfs, totally 7000,000 lines data, the size is 503MB.
Secondly, I use **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv** and **org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.LoadIncrementalHFiles** to put data into hbase.

The most import things that I did is using bulkload tool to put data into hbase,after finished bulkload, I found that the hbase table is 1.96GB. The hdfs replication is 1.
I do not know why.

Comment: how are you comparing the size?

Comment: I generate 7000,000 rows data and write the data into file.txt in windows XP filesystem, the file size is 503MB. When I put 7000,000 rows data into hbase directly, the size is 1.96GB. I set hdfs replication 1, does hbase table replication has nothing to do with hdfs replication? Do you know how to set hbase replication?

Answer (score 3):

There is a bit of overhead in storing the data since you have to store the names of the column qualifiers and such, but not 4x overhead. I have a few ideas, but definitely wouldn't mind hearing more details on the nature of the data and perhaps the stats on the table.

- Do you have compression turned on in your tables? If the data was compressed in HDFS, but then after you load it, it is not compressed, that could cause an issue.
- Maybe HBase for whatever reason isn't honoring your replication factor. Go do a `hadoop fs -dus /path/to/hbase/table/data` and see what that returns.
- Are your column qualifiers pretty big? For example, `colfam1:abc` is pretty small and won't take up much space, but `colfam1:abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz` is going to take up quite a bit of space in the grand scheme of things!

Comment: When I go to "hadoop fs -dus /path/to/hbase/table/data", the size it returns is 2108510118.The qualifiers include: asset:customer_name,asset:asset_id,asset:amount,asset:transaction_date,asset:settlement_date
I do not have compression on my table, compression is the only factor that cause the problem?
At last I tried to have a compression on my table, the operation is :
Firstly I use " create'pendings',{NAME=>'asset',COMPRESSION=>'GZ'} " to create table.
Secondly I use bulkload to put the data into table.
But compression did not work , the data size is the same as before.

Comment: 2020308035/(1024*1024)=1926MB,  1926/3=642MB, considering some overhead in hbase table, if storage 503 MB data in hbase table, maybe 642 MB is right.I set hdfs replication 1, does hbase table replication has nothing to do with hdfs replication?

Comment: When I use bulkload to put data into hbase, the replication is 1, but when I use eclipse client to put data, the replication is 3. But the total size in hbase table is the same.